# Show that the projection is $\in End(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Consider a direct sum $V=U\oplus W$ where $U,W \subseteq V$.
In my lecture notes I have been given the definition of the projection on U along W:
$E\in End(V),  E(v)=u$ with $v\in V$ and $u\in U$. I have then been given the task to prove that $E$ is indeed in $End(V)$, however, to me it seems that that simply follows from the definition, since $u\in U$ and $U\subseteq V$. How else would I prove this statement?

Comment: Isn't the question asking you to prove that $E$ is a *linear* map from $V$ into itself?

Comment: No, the question is: "Show that the projection onto $U$ along $W$ is in $End(V)$"

Comment: Proving that it is an element of $End(V)$ means that you have to prove that it is linear. See [Endomophism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism).

Comment: That does make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element of $V$ can be uniquely written as $v=u+w$ for some $u\in U$ and $v\in V$.

Thus the mapping $f:V\rightarrow U: v=u+w\mapsto u$ is well-defined.

Let $v_i=u_i+w_i\in V$ as above, $i=1,2$.

Then $f(v_1+v_2) = f((u_1+w_1)+(u_2+w_2)) = f((u_1+u_2) + (w_1+w_2)) = u_1+u_2$

and

$f(v_1)+f(v_2) = u_1 + u_2$.

Let $v=u+w\in V$ as above and $k\in K$ (scalar).

Then $f(kv) = f(ku+kw) = ku$

and

$k\cdot f(v) = ku$.

Hence $f$ is a linear mapping as claimed.

Comment: Instead of proving the linearity in two steps, would it not be equally valid to show that $f(k_1 v_1+k_2 v_2)=k_1 u_1+k_2 u_2$ and $f(k_1 v_1)+f(k_2 v_2)=k_1 u_1+k_2 u_2$?

Comment: That's right. But from the didactic point of view, two steps might be better.

Comment: Good, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

What you're requested to do is to prove that $E$ is linear.

Do do so, use the fact that by definition of $V=U\oplus W$, the decomposition for any vector exists and is unique. Then prove that for the sum of two vectors the decomposition is the sum of the decompositions by unicity. Same for the multiplication by a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

You have to prove that for every vector $v\in V$ and for every scalar $\lambda$, you have 
$$E(\lambda v)=\lambda E(v)$$
and that for every vectors $v,v'\in V$, you have
$$E(v+v')=E(v)+E(v)$$
If you want, you can perform both checks at once by proving that $E$ preserves linear combinations of vectors, that is
$$E(\lambda v+\mu v')=\lambda E(v)+\mu E(v')$$
It is not difficult to see that $E$ is indeed linear, given the direct decomposition of $V$ as $U\oplus W$, which allows you to write each vector $v\in V$ as a suitable sum of two vectors, in a unique way.